# Angular 6 - Observable never with throw

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6

I'm looking for the best way to handle an observable in Angular.
The current design is:

```
public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http
      .post(environment.apiUrl + '/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .map(response => {
        this.authenticationService.setToken(response["token"]);
        return "OK;"
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('LoginService::error', error);
        return throwError(error);
      });
  }
```

This all works fine but I don't want to be returning "OK" for no reason.

I tried the following but it says you can't assign Observable < void> to Observable< never>

```
public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<never> {
    return this.http
      .post(environment.apiUrl + '/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .map(response => {
        this.authenticationService.setToken(response["token"]);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('LoginService::error', error);
        return throwError(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: You're looking for the `tap` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .post(environment.apiUrl + '/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }).pipe(
        tap({
          next: response => {
            this.authenticationService.setToken(response["token"]);
          }, 
          error: error => {
            console.error('LoginService::error', error);
          },
        }),
      )
  }
```

The [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator adds some logic to your Observable for every emission and for the error/complete events if you so desire. The operator doesn't expect any return value and ignores them altogether, and everything else happening with the Observable will continue as usual.